# Setting file permissions on Windows 10 is very slow

Tags: windows-10, permissions, ntfs, network-drive

I have Synology active directory running on my NAS. Setting file/folder permissions using windows 10 in network drive is crazy slow. Applying permissions on one file takes few seconds, and it is impossible to work with many files. I don't know how to solve this. Do you have any idea?

[Setting security information on:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw0b9.png)

Comment: What is the network configuration and speed? The speed at which you can modify permissions is mostly bound by the speed of the communication with the device (network) and the speed at which the device reads and writes data.

Comment: can you please provide which specific method did you use to Setting file/folder permissions?